# Angular 9 forChild module not getting loaded

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In my Angular 9 application, I've created a separate admin routing module and calling it in app.module to initialize. But the routes for the components like login and signup are not getting called nor the component load on the view while getting error in the console. Only the AdminComponent is getting loaded. You can check my GitHub repository if you want to https://github.com/tridibc2/sample-angular.

AdminModule:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AdminComponent } from '../admin/admin.component';
import { SignupComponent } from '../signup/signup.component';
import { LoginComponent } from '../login/login.component';
import { ManageBlogsComponent } from '../manage-blogs/manage-blogs.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'signup', component: SignupComponent },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
    { path: 'admin', component: AdminComponent },
   { path: 'admin/blog', component: ManageBlogsComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AdminComponent,
    SignupComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    ManageBlogsComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(routes),
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AdminModule { }
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { ClientModule } from './client/client-routing/client.module';
import { AdminModule } from './admin/admin-routing/admin.module';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app.routing';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CommonModule,
    NgbModule,
    ClientModule,
    AdminModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule ],

   bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.routing.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule, } from '@angular/common';
import { BrowserModule  } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { BlogHomeComponent } from './client/blog-home/blog-home.component';
const routes: Routes =[
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'home',             component: BlogHomeComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes,{
      useHash: true
    })
  ],
  exports: [
  ],
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

[image]

Comment: Declare all your routing paths just in 1 module, cause the router module runs the routes once

Comment: but I need to separate the routes and components in separate modules itself. In the past, I did so successfully multiple times. Now after upgrading to Angular 9, it's making kind of a deal. In fact, if you check my repository you will see that I've created another such child module and called it in the main app.module.ts and it's working absolutely fine

Comment: in the AppRoutingModule export the router module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've cloned your repo from master and here is the solution I've come about.

I've created an `examples.routing.ts` and added the following code.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'user-profile', component: ProfileComponent },
  { path: 'signup', component: SignupComponent },
  { path: 'landing', component: LandingComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, BrowserModule, RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class ExamplesRoutingModule {}
```

I've added `ExamplesRoutingModule` to module imports array in `examples.module.ts`

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, FormsModule, NgbModule, ExamplesRoutingModule],
  declarations: [LandingComponent, SignupComponent, ProfileComponent],
})
export class ExamplesModule {}
```

Then inside the `app.module`, I've removed the `RouterModule` imports from imports array

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    FooterComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    NgbModule,
    FormsModule,
    ComponentsModule,
    ExamplesModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And inside `AppRoutingModule` I've exported the `RouterModule`

```
const routes: Routes =[
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'home', component: ComponentsComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes,{
      useHash: true
    })
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ],
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: thanks..it worked perfectly. So can you explain why to add RouterModule in exports array of AppRoutingModule instead of imports array inside app.module.ts

Comment: I've just followed the angular documentation on declaring routing modules. https://angular.io/guide/router#milestone-2-routing-module